# Nesting Comments Yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have a comment table, like below:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| post_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body      | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment parent_id by defautl is 0, if comment is answered, parent id insert in parent_id column.

And make a relation with User Table with below code:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

How can i show nesting?

Comment: what is the max level of the hierarchy, or let's say you are using The Adjacency List Model, how many self-joins will be required to retrieve a single path for any top-level comment?

Comment: there is no limit, a wirete a comment, b replay to a, c replay to b and ..., i need a recursive function to show the all comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define the relation inside your **Comment** model class:

```
public function getChildComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id']);
}
```

That defines the entity relationship to itself. I think it is always good to also keep related logic or handlers into helper/callable methods in the same class in a way that doesn't require having to load them all at once from database. What comes next should answer the question:

> How can i show nesting?

---

### CASE01: Inside a RESTFul application

Simply override `fields()` inside **Comment** class to always output child comments:

```php
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields['childs'] = 'childComments';
    return $fields;
}
```

That's it. [yii\rest\Serializer](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-serializer) should take care of the recursive representation and you'll get something similar to this when outputting a list of comments:

[image]

---

### CASE02: Inside a HTML web view

There is probably many ways to achieve it. The easiest and cleanest way I could think of is to tie on the template engine that Yii is already using to re-render the view holding child comments in a recursive way. As a working example, add something like what follows to your **index.php** file:

```php
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Comment;
?>

<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Comment::find(),
    ]),
    'itemView' => '_comment',
    'itemOptions' => ['style' => 'padding: 10px 50px; border: 1px solid red'],
]); ?>
```

Then create that **_comment.php** file:

```php
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
?>
    <div style="background-color: skyblue; padding: 5px 15px">
        <h4><?= Html::encode($model->id) ?></h4>
        <p><?= Html::encode($model->name) ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php
        if ($model->getChildComments()->count()) {
            echo ListView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => $model->getChildComments(),
                ]),
                'itemView' => '_comment',
                'itemOptions' => ['style' => 'padding: 10px 0 10px 50px; border: 1px dotted blue'],
            ]);
        }

    ?>
```

The template will create a new instance of itself each time it finds `childComments` linked to the represented one. With that bit of CSS paddings to show the nesting, that code should output this:

[image]

Comment: I did not understand, i wrote a function to get childeren like getChildComments(), it to level one works and don't work in recursive function, how can i use it in a recursive function?

Comment: @Masoud92m what about now?

Comment: Thanks. Glad it helped